# What are the minimum requirements for a custom Drupal 8 theme that can be enabled

Tags: theming, 8

I'm testing creating new themes in Drupal 8 and I'd like to know the very minimum it takes to create one that can be enabled. I'm not worried about any actual styling yet.

I've created a theme folder in themes called uktheme and I currently have a uktheme.info.yml file in that folder.

the contents of that file are

```
name: UK Theme
type: theme
description: 'Test theme'
package: Core

regions:
  header: Header
  primary_menu: 'Primary Menu'
  feature: 'Feature'
  content: 'Content'
  page_bottom: 'Page Bottom'
  footer_first: 'Footer first'
  footer_second: 'Footer second'
  footer_third: 'Footer third'
```

However I receive

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

when attempting to go into the appearance settings. I do not believe it's my folder structure and location because I successfully created another theme copying the content of Bartik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you've missed `core`.
Required params in `*.info.yml` are:
`name`
`description`
`type`
`core`
`regions:content`

Also you can check your `*.info.yml` for using tabs instead of spaces:

> Tabs are NOT allowed, use spaces ONLY.
>   You MUST indent your properties
>   and lists with 1 or more spaces.

See more in official docs: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/defining-a-theme

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in your name, that should be wrapped in quotes: `name: 'UK Theme'`. That space could be causing an error as it produces invalid code.

And also I am pretty sure your theme does not ship with core ;)

Comment: Hmm, it seems spaces are allowed in YAML (I always thought it was more JSON like). This probably does not solve the issue...